# Indenting inside enumerate in Latex

Tags: lists, indentation, enumerate

I am trying to do an enumerate in Latex that ends up in the following way:

1. First Step.

   1. Second Step
   2. Third Step
2. Fourth Step

I am trying to use \indent before an \item, but it doesn't work. Here is what I am trying to do in Latex:

```
\begin{enumerate}

\item start here

\indent \item continue here

\end{enumerate}
```

How can I get this to work? Thank you very much!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `enumitem` lets you achieve those kind of things. Here's your solution:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{enumerate}
\item first item
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
    \item first nested item
    \item second nested item
 \end{enumerate} 
 \item second item
\end{enumerate}
```

And here's what you seem to be looking for regarding your comment:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{enumerate}
\item first item
\item second item
{\setlength\itemindent{25pt} \item third item} 
\item fourth item
\end{enumerate}
```

For more information, check the package documentation:

http://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf

Also check out this question:
[Nested enumerate list style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41610/nested-enumerate-list-style)

And this one, too:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007627/latex-how-can-i-create-nested-lists-which-look-this-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-2-1-2

Comment: Is there a way to do it so the numbers of the outside loop are related to the ones in the inside loop? For example

1. 
2. 
  3. (indented)
  4. (indented)
5

Comment: I'm sure there is. Have you tried the documentation?

Comment: Ok, check the edited answer. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yess!! That is exactly what I meant. Thank you very much!